# Build Table with DAX that has Previous Comment

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that contains the list of comments for an opportunity.

The table has the structure:

Index - Unique Index
OptID - Identifier
CommentDate - Date
Comment- Text
I'm trying to build a table that shows only the records with the last and previous-to-last comments:

```
Table = 
    SUMMARIZE(optComment, OptComment[OptID], OptComment[Comment], "Previous Comment Date", 
    (
        VAR mxDt = MAX(optComment[CommentDate])
        VAR stld = CALCULATE(
            MAX('OptComment'[CommentDate]),
            FILTER(
                OptComment,
                OptComment[CommentDate] < mxDt)
            )   
        RETURN
        stld
))
```

But that doesn't work

As an example... I have a table that looks like this:

| Index | OptID | CommentDate | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jan 1 2000 | Comment 1 Op1 |
| 2 | 1 | Jan 5 2000 | Comment 2 Op1 |
| 3 | 1 | Jan 11 2000 | Comment 3 Op1 |
| 4 | 2 | Jan 1 2000 | Comment 1 Op2 |
| 4 | 2 | Jan 3 2000 | Comment 2 Op3 |
| 4 | 2 | Jan 5 2000 | Comment 3 Op3 |

And I'm trying to build a table virtual table to put in a variable that will look like this:

| OptID | Last CommentDate | Latest Comment | Previous Comment Dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 11 2000 | Comment 3 Op1 | Jan 5 2000 |
| 2 | Jan 5 2000 | Comment 3 Op2 | Jan 3 2000 |

Comment: I suggest you provide more detail. What are you trying to solve with this? Is persisting a new table to your data model the correct approach? I doubt it, but it depends on your requirements. I have a hunch that this is an XY Problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Marcus, I modified my question with an example

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZE(
    OptComment,
    OptComment[OptID],
    "Latest Comment", 
    CALCULATE(
        LASTNONBLANK(
            OptComment[Comment],
            1
        ),
        FILTER(
            ALL(OptComment),
            OptComment[OptID] = EARLIER(OptComment[OptID]) &&
            OptComment[CommentDate] = CALCULATE(MAX(OptComment[CommentDate]), 
                 ALLEXCEPT( OptComment, OptComment[OptID]) )
            )
        ),
    "Previous Comment",
    CALCULATE(
        LASTNONBLANK(
            OptComment[Comment],
            1
        ),
        FILTER(
            ALL(OptComment),
            OptComment[OptID] = EARLIER(OptComment[OptID]) &&
            OptComment[CommentDate] = CALCULATE(MAX(OptComment[CommentDate]), 
                FILTER(ALL(OptComment), 
                OptComment[OptID] = EARLIER(OptComment[OptID]) &&
                OptComment[CommentDate] < CALCULATE(MAX(OptComment[CommentDate]), 
                    ALLEXCEPT( OptComment, OptComment[OptID]) )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```